# What's this art style?

Tags: technique-identification, style-identification

I've seen a couple cool pictures with drawing on certain parts. I was curious if there was an actual name for this style. You can see the background and parts of the subject are the photo, and then there is drawings over other parts.
Any ideas?

Here are a few examples:

| [image: 1] | [image: 2] | [image: 3] |
| --- | --- | --- |

Thanks!

Comment: This is a technique, not a style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some sources found:
(More pertaining to the first image)
Don't think their is a definite term per se, but here is some info:

Term 1: "Illustration on photo/photograph"

When searching Google with these terms, came across the original artist related to image 1:
Source: https://www.behance.net/gallery/53008399/Vector-covered-souls
The tools used were Adobe Illustrator Draw.
Term 2: Vector drawing over photo/photograph."
From the artists portfolio they seem to have a series of vector images drawn over top of portraits of human faces. So this might be helpful.

Other terms Googled terms to look into: "Cartoon drawing over photography"

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!